# Reassigning a variable after already in use?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've got an app I'm writing in React Native. It's socketed and I have a file that controls all socket information.

```
import {Alert, AppState} from 'react-native';
import store from '../store/store';
import {updateNotifications} from '../reducers/notifications';
import {setError, clearError} from '../reducers/error';
import {updateCurrentEvent, updateEventStatus, setCurrentEvent} from '../reducers/event_details';
import {setAlert} from '../reducers/alert';
import {ws_url} from '../api/urls'

let conn = new WebSocket(ws_url);

/*
handleSocketConnections handles any actions that require rerouting. The rest are passed off to handleOnMessage
This is being called from authLogin on componentDidMount. It would be ideal to only initialize a socket conn
when a user logs in somehow, but this package gets ran when a user opens the app, meaning there are socket 
connections that don't need to exist yet.
*/

function setAppStateHandler() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', cstate => {
        if(cstate === 'active') {
            reconnect()
        }
    })
}
export const handleSocketConnections = (navigator, route) => {
    setAppStateHandler();

    conn.onmessage = e => {

        const state = store.getState();
        const msg = JSON.parse(e.data);
        const { type, payload, event_id } = msg;
        const { event } = state.event_details.event_details;

        if (type == "SET_EVENT_STATUS" && payload == "CLOSED" && event_id == event.event_id) {

            navigator.push(route)
            // store.dispatch(setAlert({
            //     message:"Event is closed, click to navigate to checkout."
            //     , scene: null
            // }))
            store.dispatch(updateEventStatus(payload));

        } else {

            handleOnMessage(msg, state)

        }
    }
}

export function reconnect() {
    //TODO: Fatal errors should redirect the mainNav to a fatal error screen. Not dismount the nav entirely, as it does now
    //and this should pop the error screen when it's fixed.
    let state = store.getState();

    conn = new WebSocket(ws_url);
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (conn.readyState == 1) {
            if (typeof state.event_details.event_details != 'undefined') {
                setSocketedEventInfo(state.event_details.event_details.event.event_id);
            }
            store.dispatch(clearError());
        } else {
            store.dispatch(setError('fatal',`Socket readyState should be 1 but it's ${conn.readyState}`))
        }
    }, 1000);
}

//Preform function on ES close.
conn.onclose = e => {
    console.log("Closing wsbidder, ", `${e.code} -- ${e.reason}`);
    //TODO: Set error here saying they need to restart the app. Maybe a 'reconnect' somehow?
    //Maybe set a store variable to socketErr and if null, all is good. Else, panic the app?

    //Use Case: Server is not started and user tries to connect to the app. String of e.message contains "Connection refused"
    store.dispatch(setError("fatal", `Socket onclose: ${e.code} -- ${e.reason}`))

};

conn.onerror = e => {
    console.log("Error at socket, ", e);
    store.dispatch(setError("fatal", `Socket onerror: ${e.message}`))
};

//Initialization function for websocket.
// conn.onopen = e => console.log("Opening wsbidder, ", e)

function handleOnMessage(msg, state) {

    switch (msg.type) {
        //These types come from the SocketWrappers on the server.
        //updateCurrentEvent should be filtering the event by event_id.
        case "EVENT_ITEMS":
            store.dispatch(updateCurrentEvent(
                msg.payload
                , state.user_info.uid
                , state.event_details.event_details.event.event_id));
            break;
        case "NOTIFICATIONS":
            //bug: this needs to filter notifications per event on the client-side.
            store.dispatch(updateNotifications(
                msg.payload
                , state.event_details.event_details.event.event_id
                , state.user_info.uid)
            );
            break;
        case "NOT_BIDDABLE":
            if (msg.event_id == state.event_details.event_details.event.event_id) {
                store.dispatch(updateEventStatus("CLOSED"));
            }
            break;
        case "PUSH_NOTIFICATION":
            const {title, message} = msg.payload;
            Alert.alert(title, message);
            break;
        default:
            console.warn(`Unrecognized socket action type: ${msg.type}`);
    }
}

//closes the socket connection and sends a reason to the server.
export const closeConn = reason => conn.close(null, reason);

export const setSocketedEventInfo = event_id => {
    //Gives the event ID to the socketed connection, which pulls end dates.
    const msg = {
        type: "UPDATE_EVENT_DETAILS"
        , payload: { event_id }
    }
    conn.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
}

export const createBid = (bid, cb) => {

    /*
     Expects:
     const new_bid = {
     item_id:    item.item_id,
     bid:        amount, //Storage keeps storing it as a string
     uid:        0, //Not needed here, but can't be null since the server wants an int.
     event_id, key, bidder
     };
     */

    const new_bid = {
        type: 'BID'
        , payload: bid
    };

    // Send this to the server socket
    conn.send(JSON.stringify(new_bid));

    //Returning the callback so the front-end knows to flip the card back over.
    return cb()
};
```

Some of the code is crap, I know. Unless you're giving true advice, which I'm always glad to follow, no need to bash it :-)

The issue I'm having is that when the socket dies (the conn variable), I can't re-initialize the socket and assign it to that conn variable. What I think is happening is all functions using the conn variable aren't using the 'new' one, still stuck to the 'old' one.

Line 9 -- Creating the original one.

Line 28 -- Creating an onMessage function for the conn object, within the handleSocketConnections function that gets called elsewhere at the start of the program

Line 57 -- Trying to re-assign a new connection to the conn variable in the reconnect function, that gets run whenever the app goes on standby (killing the socket connections).

Line 131 -- This gets called correctly from the reconnect function, connecting the socket to the server again

The reconnect() function runs correctly - the server registers the new connection with all the right info, but the app seems to still be in a weird state where there's no conn error (possibly looking at the new one??) but no actions are formed on the conn (possibly looking at the old one?).

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code really should be posted *here*.

Comment: Changed the question, added the code.

Comment: You're right - the `onclose()` and `onerror()` functions are only bound to the initially-created connection. You'll have to reassign those each time you create a new connection. You can do that by wrapping the connection-maker code in your own utility function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to start a replacement webSocket connection, then you will need to rerun all the code that hooks up to the webSocket (installs event handlers, etc...).  Because it's a new object, the old event listeners aren't associated with the new webSocket object.

The simplest way to do that is usually to create a single `webSocketInit()` function that you call both when you first create your webSocket connection and then call again any time you have to replace it with a new one.  You can pass the latest webSocket object to `webSocketInit()` so any other code can see the new object.  Individual blocks of code can register for onclose themselves if they want to know when the old one closes.

There are also more event-driven ways to do this by creating an EventEmitter that gets notified whenever the webSocket has been replaced and individual blocks of code can subscribe to that event if they want to get notified of that occurrence.

Comment: This clears things up a bit, but I'm trying to understand how I can make sure my exported connections use the new connection object. For example, the 'createBid' function.

Comment: @NathanHyland - Don't you just need the `webSocketInit()` function to call someting that updates the `conn` variable that `createBid()` uses?